# The wikipedia api seems to almost always get the word in question wrong

Tags: python, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I'm using the wikipedia python library (https://pypi.org/project/wikipedia/), and in most cases, it seems to autocorrect the terms I'm using or something so that they're often wrong.

For instance, "frog" gets changed to "food" and "crown" gets changed to "cross":

```
input: wikipedia.page("frog")
output: <WikipediaPage 'Food'>

input: wikipedia.summary("Frog")
output: 'Food is any substance consumed to provide nutritional support for an organism..."

input: wikipedia.page("crown")
output: <WikipediaPage 'Cross'>
```

When using wikipedia.search, it seems to provide an appropriate list, but I don't know how to utilize this to get the correct page when using .summary, etc:

```
input: print(wikipedia.search("frog"))
output: ['Frog', 'FROG', 'The Princess and the Frog', 'Boiling frog', 'Frog legs', 'Frogger', 'The Scorpion and the Frog', 'Pepe the Frog', 'The Frog Prince', 'Common frog']
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is due to the default for `auto_suggest` on `summary()` being `True`.

According to the [docs](https://wikipedia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code.html#api), you can change this to `False` and it will correctly return the summary for `frog`.

```
wikipedia.summary("Frog", auto_suggest=False)
#'A frog is any member of a diverse and largely carnivorous group of short-bodied, tailless amphibians composing the order Anura (literally without tail in Ancient Greek)
```

---

It seems, for whatever odd reason the the `API's` `suggest()` feature is... weird.
It would likely be best to keep `auto_suggest` to `False`..

```
wikipedia.suggest("Frog")
#'food'
wikipedia.suggest("Steak")
#'steam'
wikipedia.suggest("Dog")
#'do'
wikipedia.suggest("cat")
#'cats'
wikipedia.suggest("david attenborough")
#None
```

Comment: Bizarre API implementation. There's an exact match, but it won't retrieve it. I wonder what their justification is.

Comment: @jarmod seems the `suggest()` feature is.. not very good at suggesting? It almost never matches what you're looking for.

Comment: The suggestion is something you can as a replacement search query if the original search query didn't yield good results. It is not a title and it doesn't make sense to take it over the top search result (which is the exact match for all of these examples). The script should be fixed.

Comment: It seems largely unmaintained, with a zillion bug reports about this issue ([e.g.](https://github.com/goldsmith/Wikipedia/issues/227)) and even a [pull request](https://github.com/goldsmith/Wikipedia/pull/131). You might be better off looking for an alternative tool or a better-maintained fork.